# Displaying results of php associative array echod in JSON object to jquery.post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, html

I am having a great deal of difficulty getting jquery.post() to work properly. Everything seems to be in order but I cannot get my json to display on the screen. I have been working on this for about the last day or so and I am posting here as a last resort. I saw a lot of questions posted on here about ajax.post and a lot of good answers. However most of those Q&As dealt with echoing back simple variables. i.e a single int. Unfortunately, since I am working with an array I don't think the same or similar solutions will work for me. 
This is a look at the php that is being returned to the first page. We'll refer to this segment as page #2

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, todos FROM to_do_list WHERE uid =?"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['SESS_ID'])){
        echo "Binding param failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()){
        echo "Execute failed block 2: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " .$stmt->error;
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $todos);
    if ($stmt->store_result()){
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
        while($stmt->fetch()){
                  $results[] =  array('id' => $id, 'todos' => $todos);     
        }
        echo json_encode($results);
    }
```

Here is a look at the relevant portion of the 1st page, or the calling page:

```
        <div id="content">


    </div>


    <form title="todosubmitter" id="todoPost" autocomplete="off">
        Add To Do:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="todo" class="required formStyle error">
        <!--<input type="reset" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="$.post('dbAccessor.php', $('#todoPost').serialize());"> -->
         <input type="reset" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="$.post('dbAccessor.php', $('#todoPost').serialize(), function(data) { $('#content').html(data);}, 'json');"> 
    </form>
```

No matter what I put in there I cannot get any of my json data to be displayed on the screen. I have tried numerous things. No success.

Also. in before your php doesn't work and isn't returning anything to the 1st page:

```
[{"id":98,"todos":"asdfa"},{"id":97,"todos":"asdfasdf"},{"id":96,"todos":"adsfasdfadf"},{"id":95,"todos":"asdfasdf"},{"id":94,"todos":"sadfasdf"},{"id":93,"todos":"asdfasdf"},{"id":92,"todos":"adfgadfga"},{"id":91,"todos":"asdfasd"},{"id":90,"todos":"asdfadf"},{"id":89,"todos":"asdfafd"},{"id":88,"todos":"asdf"},{"id":87,"todos":"asdf"},{"id":86,"todos":"asdf"},{"id":85,"todos":"asdf"},{"id":84,"todos":"dfa"},{"id":83,"todos":"asdf"},{"id":82,"todos":"do"},{"id":81,"todos":"asdf"},{"id":80,"todos":"asdf"},{"id":79,"todos":"asdf"}]
```

Thank you in advance to whom ever can end this mystery for me.

Comment: what does js console say?

Comment: Your JSON sample would not evaluate to html once parsed, so `$('#content').html(data);` won't put anything in `#content`.

Comment: The jquery.post() is supposed to evaluate the data as JSON and turn it into a js object. So I didn't think that was a problem.
Also, there are no errors in the js console. Just nothing happens.